# Making 2 one-to-one relationships from table A twice to table B using Hibernate (annotations)

Tags: hibernate, annotations, one-to-one

Let's start with an example:

```
Person
    Address homeAddress
    Address workAddress

Address
    Person person
```

Addresses are not shared with other persons (so it's definitely a one-to-one relationship.

Fairly easy to set up in a database, but I don't know how to configure this in hibernate.  I don't want to work with a list of addresses in the Person object, and I definitely need the link back from address to person.

A workaround is to make a OneToMany, use a differentiator on Address ('home' or 'business') and when getting / setting / adding addresses on the Person object, deal with the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it like this:

```
Person
    Address homeAddress
    Address workAddress

Address
    Person personForHomeAddress
    Person personForWorkAddress
    Person getPerson(){
      return personForHomeAddress != null ? personForHomeAddress : personForWorkAddress
    }
    void setPerson(Person person){
      ...
    }
```

It's not optimal, since I need 2 columns in my address-table, but I can stick with 2 one-to-one relationships in hibernate.

Any other ideas?